# Strange behaviour with content-type header

Tags: php, ajax

I developped a wordpress plugin to draw chart from data files. It consists of three ajax call with jason datas.
In locahost it works fine. But in production, the last ajax failed sometimes (two others never !). I saw each times it failed in web console, that response header content-type is not as attempted : attempted = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", received = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Debug console :
--- Header response ---
content-type : text/html; charset=UTF-8 referrer-policy : strict-origin-when-cross-origin x-frame-options : SAMEORIGIN
--- Header request ---
Accept : application/json Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 contentType : application/json;charset=utf-8 dataType : json

server side in PHP :

```
if (...) {
  header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($choice);
}   
elseif (...) {
  header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode(AXIS_X); 
 }
elseif (...) {
  header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($arr,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // return datas H/F for specified indice and CSP}   
            } else echo json_encode("PHP : array key not exist for AxisY !");
    }   else echo json_encode("PHP : some variable not set for AxisY !");
(...) else echo json_encode("PHP : UID not set  !");
wp_die(); // Close session properly
```

}

and jquery side :

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        url: the_ajax_plugin.ajaxurl,
        global: false,
        headers: {
            'dataType': 'json',
            //'contentType': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',  
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        type: "POST"
    });
   (...) // Last AJAX call
          $.ajax({
            data: {
              'action': 'chartjs_data_hook',
              'get_value': [uid,"SELECT-AXISY", csp, indice,ets]
            }
                        
      }).success(function(response) {
        axisY = response;
        // Fill table (ancienneté, âge, effectif)                      
        drawTable($(document.body), axisY);

        $("#div_myChart").append('<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>');
        ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
        drawChart(axisX, axisY, salaire);

      }).fail(function(response) {
        alert("Get datas Y - Bad request !" + response);
      });
```

Comment: To start with, put an `else` in there as a failsafe that throws an exception.

Comment: When it fails, status code = successfull = 200 and header response = 'content-type
 text/html;charset=utf-8' **always** ! Attempted header response when it's ok = 'content-type application/json;charset=utf-8'.

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever you perform a direct stream write as you are doing with `header` followed by an `echo`, it is recommended to immediately perform an `exit`, don't wait to the end to do that, this fixes a lot of common bugs. By doing that, you can also turn all of your `elseif` statements into `if` statements, too, because the `if` statements terminate. Did you clear any existing headers? For debugging purposes, try switching to `GET` and use your browser instead of AJAX so that you can see things a little easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. First I will try to remove elseif and place die just after echo. Clear existing headers : Whats about ?

Comment: I made modifications according to your comments without any change in behaviour.Sometimes it goes wrong ... Last chance with GET instead POST.